# Setting a windows icon that is located in a different assembly from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

From XAML, I am attempting to set the icon from the Window control.

The .ico file is located in a different assembly (no subfolders). I *can* get this to work when I just add the file to this assembly, but my goal is to make this work with having only the original .ico file, and having it stay where it is.

I have tried:

Icon="pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/IconFile.ico" as well as Icon="/ReferencedAssembly;component/IconFile.ico"

Even without the nasty blue squiggles, when I try to run I get errors of:

'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' with an InnerException of "Could not load file or assembly..... The System cannot find the file specified."

Win7, .NET 4

This seems like it should be simple enough, yet I am stumped. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: This problem is more specific to loading the assembly which you have referred in the xaml. May be the assembly is not in the same location as that of the application which you are using . Start VS cmd prompt and run FUSLOGVW.exe. Go to settings , enable CustomLogPath and provide a folder where logs needs to be generated , select Bind all failure to disk option. Now run your application .Go to the path which you have configured in the Fuslogvw.exe and you will find the folder name with your application name. Check the html file inside it to know more about the error

Comment: Thanks. That certainly helped me pinpoint the issue - I got it now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to srsyogesh for helping get some additional error info.

I noticed it was failing to download the assembly initially, and that was a silly error on my part from failing to notice that that reference was completely missing.

With that fixed, it was followed by a "ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.", with an inner exception of "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". That was apparently caused by a conflict of "x86" vs "Any CPU" Platform Target in the build settings. Changed the one that said "Any CPU" to "x86", and voila.

Comment: Another way of doing this (if you only need an individual file), is to skip the referencing entirely, and all the file as a link to the assembly.